# cURL doesn't always follow redirect

Tags: bash, shell, redirect, curl, cygwin

I'm new here and have a question which I've looked into and have been trying to resolve for some time now. I'm developing a web crawler-esque bash script; pretty simple.
I wish to visit a site in which a certain ID is appended to the url. I wish to increment through these given passed parameters as bounds. I have had some success with this but I've noticed it isn't always reliable. I'm currently using cygwin as I'm on windows and am wondering if this is the matter. Also, because it is a lengthy process I've duplicated the file and have each incrementing by 2. I've looked into similar issues people are having and it's been brought up that cookies need to be managed. I was wondering I would go about this.

Script:

```
for i in $(eval echo {$1..$2..2})
do

url=`curl -b a,, -w "%{url_effective}\n" -L -s -S -o /dev/null http://website.com/page/Redirected_String/$i`
echo $i - $url

done
```

I have even run just the cURL command independently from the BASH loop and it still sometimes fails to follow the page's redirect.

```
curl -b a,, -w "%{url_effective}\n" -L -s -S -o /dev/null http://website.com/page/Redirected_String/100
```

What is even more odd is that I have a copy of the script on my iPhone and when I run via mobile terminal, it seems more reliable. I'm running on cygwin and I noticed that when this happens, the output string of each supposed redirected webpage is churned out much quicker.

Could this be a hardware issue? I'm very confused by this and have looked all over for help to no avail.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: What isn't always reliable? What doesn't work? Are there errors?

Comment: @EtanReisner no errors, it just sometimes doesn't pick up the redirection. I'll visit one of the output urls that doesn't seem to redirect but in the browser the Redirected_String will be changed.

Comment: Are you sure that's curl and not the website being broken? Tell curl to dump the full transaction to a log file and see what you get in those cases (or use a packet capture).

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm positive it's the script. The thing is, I don't know how to reproduce the results. One time I'll get the redirection and the console will show the new redirected link and then other times it will look something like (http://website.com/page/Redirected_String/101) when it should be something like (http://website.com/page/item/101) How would I go about that? Sorry, I'm not real familiar with the flags/syntax of cURL.

Comment: Add `--trace OUTPUT.$i` to the command line or just run tcpdump/wireshark/etc. before you run the script. And yes, that sort of failure sounds exactly like the remote website failing to send you the correct redirection headers/etc. on some of your requests because curl is always requesting the `Reidrected_String` version.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `for i in $(eval echo {$1..$2..2})` you can do this in BASH arithmetic brackets `((...))`:

```
for ((i=$1; i<=$2; i+=2)); do echo "$i"; done
```

Comment: Thanks! What I have been doing in the command is calling both scripts with & and alter the second scripts starting point by 1.

Comment: You can just replace `echo "$i"` with your curl command and whatever else you want to do inside loop.

Comment: Thanks again! That works as far as the command to run but I'm still having problems with consistency of cURL. Any thoughts? Your insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *consistency of cURL*. Test your `curl` command independently on command line and see if you're getting correct output.

Comment: It sometimes is hit or miss. I'm wondering if it has to do with the cURL command being run on Cygwin because I'm using the same script on my Mobile terminal on my iPhone and it is much more reliable.

Comment: I also have a hard time believing it's the site because I just tested on both platforms and my pc didn't pick up the redirect whereas my phone did. This was done independently from the script and was just the url variable printed for 1 number.

Comment: If you see my answer I didn't even provide you curl answer. I just showed you how to use BASH loop without eval.